# Python - Where is the pip executable after install?

Tags: python, installation, pip

Since I am on a server and do not have admin privilege, I need to install my own version of python and pip locally. After installed python, I used the code `python get-pip.py --user` which is on the [official site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#id10). I get the following return and seems pip is successfully installed. But I do not know where is the pip executable so that I cannot add it to the system environment. So where is it installed?

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-27.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip setuptools wheel
```

Comment: Check in `~/.local/bin`

Comment: Or `PYTHON_DIR\Scripts` on Windows.

Comment: Since I installed my own python at a local folder, if I ran pip, it will say /usr/local/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory, how can I tell pip where to find the local python2.7?

Comment: @lolibility Sounds like another question. Check for dupes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix, `pip install --user` ... drops scripts into `~/.local/bin`

pip sould be somewhere around `~/.local`

Comment: I found it, thanks! But now there is another question. Since I installed my own python at a local folder, if I ran pip, it will say /usr/local/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory, how can I tell pip where to file the python2.7?

Comment: Well this i don't know... sorry